# Scansnap Organiser - Preview window not appearing

Tags: windows-xp

A bit of a long shot, but I have a scansnap S300 scanner which is bundled with the scansnap organiser software. On the top bar the last button is an image of a magnifying glass and a paper ("Show/Hide popup thumbnails" is shown in the status bar on hover), which when selected should pop up a preview of the scanned document when you select one.

This used to work, but has stopped working. I am not sure if it is because I have a dual monitor setup and the pc has become confused and is opening the window off screen. However, even if this is the case the window does not have a separate taskbar button so cannot select move and move it over manually.

I'm reluctant to reinstall, but think that that may be the only option.

Has anyone encountered this problem and resolved it, or reinstalled and found it not to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted Fujitsu support who responded incredibly quickly. They were unaware of such an issue, and suggested that I needed to reinstall the app. Which I did, to no avail.

I then noticed that the window probably was opening off page and decided to try swapping the windows around in the Display Properties (Rather than the NVIDIA control panel which I usually use). Lo and Behold the window appeared on my right hand monitor which was configured now as my left. I could then move it to the other monitor and revert the settings. Now I have full access to the window as before.